# How to feed data in time tag from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using time field in html and want to feed data from angular controller

```
<input type="time"  ng-model="bt_time" class="form-control" style="width: 20%" required>
```

I want to feed data from controller

```
$scope.bt_time='12:30';
```

But I am getting error

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/ngModel/datefmt?p0=12%3A30

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/6tftgvk3/2/

Comment: i tried this method only but didn't worked for me.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this below code:

```
$scope.bt_time =  new Date(2017, 0, 1, 12, 30, 0);
```